# 'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'n_features_': 0

Tags: python, azure-machine-learning-service

i had deployed my random Forest Regressor on AzureML.when i tried to request the scoring url i got the "'DecisionTreeRegressor' object has no attribute 'n_features_': 0"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJU5a.png)

[My request code and error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVwEP.png)